# Is there a name for the great circle where latitude and longitude are equal?

Tags: geodesy

Is there a name for the great circle where latitude and longitude are equal? I have attempted a google search but only the equator and the prime meridian are defined in the sources I can find. ( It is of relevance in developing a map application which keeps track of latitude and longitude ).

Comment: I think the answer is probably not, but maybe others have some idea. I doubt if it would be useful for anything (maybe some satellites might fly on such an orbit).

Comment: Your question seems to be missing vital info .. if latitude and longitude are equal = non-changing .. how can there be a circle .. that defines only a point

Comment: @eagle275 as latitude $\phi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and longitude $\lambda\in[-\pi,\pi]$, there should be a curve formed by the points where $\phi = \lambda$. I hade made the (erroneous, as pointed out by tfb) assumption that this curve would be a great circle.

Comment: There's a good answer. But it's also worth mentioning that this line doesn't mean anything - because longitude is arbitrary. There's no good reason for any particular meridian to be defined as zero.

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon the 'Prime meridian' or 'Greenwich meridian' is the name of a great circle (or at least half a circle). That longitude it is arbitrary doesn't mean you can't have a great circle with a name defined by it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The curve where latitude and longitude are equal is not a great circle.  But as joe khool writes in his [excellent answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/19502/18801), it's called the **curve of Viviani**!  It's easy to see that the curve is not a great circle, because, using naïve spherical coordinates (in radians) $(\phi,\lambda)$ with $\lambda$ being longitude and $\phi$ being latitude (zero at equator), this curve passes through $(0,0)$, and also through $(\pi/2,\pi/2)$ which is the north pole ($(\pi/2,\lambda)$ is the north pole for any $\lambda$),  But it also passes through, say, $(1,1)$ which is not on the great circle the between previous two points.

In fact the curve you get looks like this:

[image: not a great circle]

---

**Note.** I plotted this by defining Cartesian coordinates in the obvious way:

$$
\begin{align}
 x &= R\cos\phi\cos\lambda\\
 y &= R\cos\phi\sin\lambda\\
 z &= R\sin\phi
\end{align}$$

and then plotting $(x,y,z)$ for $\phi = \lambda$ and $\lambda\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

An earlier version of this answer plotted $(x,y,z)$ for $\phi = \lambda$ and $\lambda\in[-\pi,\pi]$.  This means that $\phi$ takes values which are not in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ of course.  I had assumed that these points would end up around the back of the planet: that you'd get a kind of 'S' which wraps around the planet, but in fact it ends up around the front of it again:

[image: also not a great circle]

This surprised me!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106083/discussion-on-answer-by-tfb-is-there-a-name-for-the-great-circle-where-latitude).

Answer (score 19):

If the Earth was a sphere, then the curve in the last picture of tfb's answer is the [curve of Viviani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve#Parametric_representation); otherwise, if you make the oblate spheroid assumption, you get a slightly distorted version of this curve.

More generally, a [*clélie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cl%C3%A9lie) is the name given to any spherical curve where the longitude $\varphi$ and colatitude $\theta$ have the relationship $\varphi=c\theta,\quad c>0$, and the curve of Viviani corresponds to the locus of a geosynchronous orbit, $c=1$.

Comment: [here are some](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37454/121020) geosynchronous orbits and they do look similar, If [Viviani's curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviani%27s_curve) were a geosynchronous orbit then it would have to correspond to inclination of 90 degrees. Is it possible to add a link (or some math) that supports the curve is in fact a synchronous orbit in a rotating frame? *Thanks!*

Comment: also (just fyi) [Is an Earth synchronous (?) polar orbit possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40809/12102)

Comment: @uhoh, I think that deserves to be a question on its own. ;)

Comment: what a remarkable coincidence! :-) [Is a polar geosynchronous orbit described by Viviani's curve?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/42097/12102)